# React.js - Loading single post data from API correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am fairly new to React, and trying to work my way through how I should properly be loading data from my API for a single post.

I have read that I should be using "componentDidMount" to make my GET request to the API, but the request is not finished by the time the component renders. So my code below does not work, as I am recieving the error: "Cannot read property setState of undefined".

What I am doing wrong here? Should I be calling setState from somewhere else? My simple component is below - thanks.

```
import React from 'react';
import Header from './Header';
import axios from 'axios';

class SingleListing extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            listingData: {}
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {

        // Get ID from URL
        var URLsegments = this.props.location.pathname.slice(1).split('/');

        // Load the listing data
        axios.get('/api/listing/' + URLsegments[1])
            .then(function(res){

                let listingDataObject = res.data;
                console.log(listingDataObject);
                this.setState({
                    listingData: listingDataObject
                });

            })
            .catch(function(err){
                console.log(err);
            });

    }


    render() {

        console.log('helsdfdsfsdflssosso');
        console.log(this.state.listingData);

        return (
            <div className="SingleListing">
                <Header />
                <div className="container">

                    <div>Property Address: {this.state.listingData.propertyAddress}</div>
                    This is a single listing
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }

}
export default SingleListing;
```

Comment: I think this is a scope issue. Try putting "var self = this" in componentDidMount. and then doing "self.setState({........whatever state})". "this" in the axios.get function is referring to the scope of axios.get, not the SingleListing component, that's why self will refer to the SingleListing component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to change what you render depending on whether the data is loaded or not yet.

Also, you should use arrow functions when handling the `axios` response, otherwise `this` is not set correctly.

```
class SingleListing extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      listingData: null,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // Get ID from URL
    const URLsegments = this.props.location.pathname.slice(1).split('/');

    // Load the listing data
    axios
      .get(`/api/listing/${URLsegments[1]}`)
      .then(res => {
        const listingDataObject = res.data;
        console.log(listingDataObject);
        this.setState({
          listingData: listingDataObject,
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }

  render() {
    const isDataLoaded = this.state.listingData;

    if (!isDataLoaded) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    }

    return (
      <div className="SingleListing">
        <Header />
        <div className="container">
          <div>Property Address: {this.state.listingData.propertyAddress}</div>
          This is a single listing
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SingleListing;
```

Comment: Dammit - thanks for the answers guys. Can't believe I forgot my fat arrow functions, that was half the issue! Great this works perfect elas - cheers.

Answer (score 1):

`this` is out of scope you need to include it. here is a solution using es2015 arrow functions `=>`

```
axios.get('/api/listing/' + URLsegments[1])
        .then((res) => {
            let listingDataObject = res.data;
            console.log(listingDataObject);
            this.setState({
                listingData: listingDataObject
            });

        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
```